# How to create virtual username.domain.com using .htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard

I know there are plenty of questions like I asked, but searching all day the soluation, I didnt find right one that would work for me, therefore I asked question.
Here is `.htaccess` code I have to view user profiles:

```
RewriteRule  ^users/([^/\.]+)/$ viewProfile.php?user=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule  ^users/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/$ viewProfile.php?user=$1&usr_profile=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

And using this rewrite users profile *URL* is:

```
http://www.domain.com/users/username.html
```

Inside of this type of *URL*, I would like to create subdomain users *URL*, like:

```
http://username.domain.com
```

Can anyone suggest the solution?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your vhost is setup to accept requests for `*.domain.com`. Then add this above your other rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ viewProfile.php?user=%1 [L,QSA]
```